# Error in retrieving root element in xml using lxml python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I have following xml:
 val='''

```
<bookstore>
   <book>
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

I want to retrieve first element, i.e. "bookstore" and I am doing:

```
etree.parse(StringIO(xml1))
val.xpath('bookstore')
```

but it is giving [] empty list, but same script is working when I am doing for book, val.xpath('book').

How to retrieve first element??

Comment: Per Python docs `This module provides limited support for XPath expressions for locating elements in a tree. The goal is to support a small subset of the abbreviated syntax; a full XPath engine is outside the scope of the module.` https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
/bookstore  # child
```

or

```
//bookstore  # descendant at any depth
```

I don't think you are targeting the nodes correctly atm

Comment: but I am not getting how it is working for "book" element and not working for its parent "bookstore"